# Can I have a Wordpress is_page array range?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the Wordpress **is_page** conditional tag frequently, and typically I am defining a single ID, or an array of ID's to include, or exclude from displaying some custom code.

What I'm trying to figure out, is whether I can define a range of ID's to feed in as an argument.

**Here is a simple example of using the is_page condition:**

```
<?php if(is_page( 5 ): ?>
    <p>This is some text</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Here is a simple example of using the id_page condition with an array:**

```
<?php if(is_page( array( 5,6,7 ) ): ?>
    <p>This is some text</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**What I'd like to do, is have this where I can pass through an argument, and define that as a range of ID's such as 5-7:**

```
$arg = 5-7;
<?php if(is_page( $arg ): ?>
    <p>This is some text</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where I'm defining the arg, I think it's a matter of maybe setting a boundary, defining an array, and placing that in a foreach statement, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page, you can't use it as a range. However, I'd use this function instead

```
$isPage = false;
foreach(range(5, 7) as $page)
{
    if(is_page($page))
        $isPage = true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah after reading the codex, I was bummed they didn't have anything set for ranges, but let me take a look at the function there and see what happens.

Comment: you can use like if(is_page(1) || is_page(2) || is_page(3) )